# AWS API Gateway where is the `settings` menu option?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Newbie here on AWS in general.

Nonetheless, I was able to setup the AWS API Gateway to manage access to my API.

Now I want to follow the instructions out of this [AWS knowledge-base page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/).  Unfortunately, I have no clue where the `settings` menu item is for both my `API` and the `stage`.

What I see on the UI is this:

[image: API Gateway menu]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I selected to manage an `HTTP API`.  I should have selected a `REST API`